# Custom action button in push notification react native android

Tags: push-notification, react-native, android-push-notification

I want to develop push notifications which has custom action buttons (2 buttons) which says "Yes" & "No" clicking on "Yes" button calls an REST Api without actually opening the app.

The notification should work irrespective of whether the app is in foreground or background.

I am currently using firebase for showing PushNotification specific react-native-firebase v5.

Have tried "android actions" from react native firebase, but unable to get action button on push notification.

```
    // Set up your listener
firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
    // notificationOpen.action will equal 'test_action'
});

// Build your notification
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
  .setTitle('Android Notification Actions')
  .setBody('Action Body')
  .setNotificationId('notification-action')
  .setSound('default')
  .android.setChannelId('notification-action')
  .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max);
// Build an action
const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action('test_action', 'ic_launcher', 'My Test Action');
// Add the action to the notification
notification.android.addAction(action);

// Display the notification
firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
```

I want it in PushNotification not as an local notification.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, How did you fixed it? I do have to integrate exactly the same work.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733439/how-to-display-action-buttons-in-android-notification-when-app-is-closed